# Calling a Vector3 from inside an 'if' statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry if the title seemed vague, couldn't word it any better. however, I can explain the problem.

As a programming noob, I barely understand anything, however, this just seems to boggle me.

```
        if (gotPos == false)
        {
            // find the target position relative to the player:
            Vector3 dir = target.position - this.transform.position;
            // keep y direction the same.
            dir.y = 0;
            // calculate movement at the desired speed:
            Vector3 movement = dir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            gotPos = true;
        }
        else if (gotPos == true) //anything past this causes errors with Vector3 struct names. ;(
        {
            if (movement.magnitude > dir.magnitude) movement = dir;
            {
                // move the character:
                cc.Move(movement);
                applyGravity();
                Debug.Log(target.position);
            }
        }
```

Whenever I click, I want to set the target position **once** and then let the object move to that target position. However, not encasing that in an if statement will constantly check for the target position, and the object will always go to it. However, the problem with the 'if' statement is that I get errors like [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvrWh.png)

Obviously the Vector 3 structs DO exist, how do I allow using the Vector3 structs inside an if statement?

Comment: In c#, variables have a specific scope and are not visible outside that scope. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to familiarize yourself with the term *scope*.

Basically, a variable lives only within the closest curly braces `{` and `}` and does not exist outside.

In your case, `Vector3 movement` only exists inside the `if (gotPos == false) {...}` part, but not anywhere else, i.e. not inside `else if (gotPos == true){ ... }`.

If you want to use it in both parts, you need to declare it before/outside the `if` statement like

```
Vector3 movement;
if (gotPos == false)
{
    ...
    movement = dir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    ...
}
else if (gotPos == true)
{
    ...
}
```

Given that this code must be inside a method, you'll likely have other curly braces around this code = it is now in different scope. In that case, `Vector3 movement` does not survive the method and the assignment would be useless. Thus, you need to make it live even longer and make it a field like so:

```
Vector3 movement;

void mymethod() // this may be different in your code
{
    ...
    if (gotPos == false)
    {
        ...
        movement = dir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        ...
    }
    else if (gotPos == true)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the variable `movement` in the `else if` part of the `if` statement, but you declared it in the first part of the `if` statement.

In other words, the `if` part of the statement was skipped entirely to get to the `else if` section, hence the variable never got declared. I would suggest something like this for a variable that you want to use in both parts of an `if` statement

```
Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero;
Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

if (gotPos == false)
        {
            // find the target position relative to the player:
            dir = target.position - this.transform.position;
            // keep y direction the same.
            dir.y = 0;
            // calculate movement at the desired speed:
            movement = dir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            gotPos = true;
        }
        else if (gotPos == true) //anything past this causes errors with Vector3 struct names. ;(
        {
            if (movement.magnitude > dir.magnitude) movement = dir;
            {
                // move the character:
                cc.Move(movement);
                applyGravity();
                Debug.Log(target.position);
            }
        }
```

You need to declare them outside the `if` statement so they can be used in either part.

Also, in the `else if` section both `movement` and `dir` are referenced before being set, so you'll need to set them to something before they get to this point, I set them to `Vector3.zero` in the example so the code will work.